# Running AoT changes the layout

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I've found something really fishy behavior in the project that I dont understand and I havent found any solution for why it behaves like this.

It's an Angular application and we upgraded from ng5 to ng7, also upgraded bootsrap along the way.

And when we run "ng serve" it looks like this:
[image]

And when we run "ng serve --aot" it looks like this:
[image]

I've inspected the whole dom and pulling my hair. And I cant see any difference between the two versions.

So why do AoT ruin the layout?

Br

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code for the elements in the screenshot?

Comment: Probably while upgrading your css of your framework used has also updated

Comment: @PardeepJain that wouldn't change the output between the JIT and AOT modes. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue, if possible, as some people can't see images on SOF.